# Flutter: get message "Operation not permitted" when sync grandle in android studio and flutter run

Tags: flutter, android-studio

when i try to run a old project by flutter run:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file '/Users/anhdinhhoangquang/Desktop/cloudv-app/android/settings.gradle' line: 8

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'.
> /Users/anhdinhhoangquang/Desktop/cloudv-app/.flutter-plugins (Operation not permitted)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 820ms
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                           1,564ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

this is my **settings.gradle**

```
include ':app'

def flutterProjectRoot = rootProject.projectDir.parentFile.toPath()

def plugins = new Properties()
def pluginsFile = new File(flutterProjectRoot.toFile(), '.flutter-plugins')
if (pluginsFile.exists()) {
    pluginsFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader -> plugins.load(reader) }
}

plugins.each { name, path ->
    def pluginDirectory = flutterProjectRoot.resolve(path).resolve('android').toFile()
    include ":$name"
    project(":$name").projectDir = pluginDirectory
}
```

and i also try to open by android studio and sync gradle file but got message like this
[image]

i also update my gradle but nothing happend [image]
[image]

Comment: Have you installed `Flutter`?

Comment: yeah of course.